# Sign a name with ASCII characters or in my native language?

Tags: signature, name, language

I submitted some patches for GNU software, and its maintainers accepted them.

They want me to assign the copyright to the FSF, so they sent me a legal document.

Here is the text at the end of that document (and [a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIGgv.png)):

```
Thank you for the contribution!

Signed:                                   Accepted by the Free Software Foundation
     (Chinese name 谢骐,
       or ASCII characters Xie Qi?)
________________________________________  ________________________________________
Xie Qi                                    John Hsieh, Deputy Director


________________________________________  ________________________________________
Date                                      Date

              SPELL OUT THE NAME OF THE MONTH WHEN WRITING THE DATE
```

##### Q:

Should I sign my name that has *the force of law in my country*,

or just ASCII characters as indicated below the line?

If both are OK, which one is recommended? What's the reason? Why not recommend another one?

Comment: Why not write both?

Comment: @phoog: Thank you for your advice!  I know little about US law.  May I ask if this will have *a legal effect*?  Is it possible to be ambiguous?  If not, is it OK to sign in this form: `谢骐 (Xie Qi)`?

Comment: Does https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/38347/can-i-sign-legal-documents-with-a-smiley-face answer your question? (You might as well sign "Sun Wukong"; what matters is that it is reasonably well-established that _you_ signed the document and agree to be bound by it. If the document with your name was sent to your mail or email address and returned signed to their offices, the presumption is strong that you were the one to sign it.)

Comment: AFAIK no Mainland, Taiwanese or Hong Kong law requires the use of signatures in Chinese characters to have legal force, although Mainland passport applications require a particular signature that is not only in Chinese characters but also in the Zheng Kai script style.